# inline assembly - check if word is a palindrome

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I am writing a simple program that uses inline assebly to check if given word is a palindrome. The problem is it doesn't return correct answers. During debugging I found out that there's something wrong with esi register (the value in `al` is correct (`'a'`), but in `bl` it's not (0). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char s[] = "arabara";
    int sizeofstring = 8; // size of s[]
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1; //flag when is_palindrome
    __asm
    {
        lea edi, s 
        mov esi, edi 
        add esi, sizeofstring
        dec esi  //point to the last char 

        mov ecx, sizeofstring
        cmp ecx, 1
        je is_palindrome  //single char is always a palindrome 

        shr ecx, 1   //divide by 2 

nextchar: 
        mov al, [edi]
        mov bl, [esi]
        cmp al, bl
        jne stop
        inc edi
        dec esi
        loop nextchar

    is_palindrome:
    mov eax, y
    mov x, eax //change flag to 1 

stop: 
    }

    cout << x  << endl; //shoud print 1 when palindrome
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You originally add 8 to the start address (_EDI_) of the string and put that address in _ESI_. That is a pointer to the character one past the nul(0) terminator. You subtract 1 from ESI which is the same as [EDI+7]. The character at [ESI] ([EDI+7]) then is the nul(0) terminator. Maybe you meant to subtract 2 from _ESI_ and not just one? The alternative would be set `sizeofstring` to 7 instead of 8 (ignoring the nul terminator in the length). In effect the first time through your loop you compare 'a' with '\0` and they are different of course.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working now.

Comment: Why are you doing this using inline assembly? If you are trying to learn assembly language programming, then inline assembly is a very bad thing to be using. Just configure Visual Studio to execute MASM, and you can continue using the IDE and debugger. If you *aren't* trying to learn assembly, then it would be much faster and simpler to write the code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You set `sizeofstring` to 8, but your string "arabara" is seven characters long.

Comment: `"arabara"` is 8 characters long.  Do not forget about the terminating null character